# Log rain sensor data with time to CSV using Python on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have made a small weather station, the latest sensor I have added is a 'rain sensor', which can be seen [here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/204523988582?mkevt=1&mkcid=1&mkrid=710-53481-19255-0&campid=5338365712&toolid=20006&customid=EB197597567&amdata=enc%3A1GK9DCBABQ1SSnBnjZjaU1Q90&_trkparms=ispr%3D1). I have followed  a simple guide which correctly reads if the sensor is detecting rain or not. Using the following code...

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

POWER_PIN = 12  # GPIO pin that provides power to the rain sensor
DO_PIN = 7     # GPIO pin connected to the DO pin of the rain sensor

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(POWER_PIN, GPIO.OUT)  # configure the power pin as an OUTPUT
    GPIO.setup(DO_PIN, GPIO.IN)

def loop():
    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # turn the rain sensor's power ON
    time.sleep(0.01)                   # wait 10 milliseconds

    rain_state = GPIO.input(DO_PIN)

    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.LOW)  # turn the rain sensor's power OFF

    if rain_state == GPIO.HIGH:
        print("The rain is NOT detected")
    else:
        print("The rain is detected")

    time.sleep(1)  # pause for 1 second to avoid reading sensors frequently and prolong the sensor lifetime

def cleanup():
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        setup()
        while True:
            loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cleanup()`
```

I am struggling to write this to a csv file, logging every minute. Any help would be appreciated...

I have tried using chatGPT but am having no luck. Using the code shown below which should work, i get:

return False
^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

```
import csv
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO



# Function to check if rain is detected (replace this with your actual rain detection logic)
def is_rain_detected():
    POWER_PIN = 12  # GPIO pin that provides power to the rain sensor
DO_PIN = 7     # GPIO pin connected to the DO pin of the rain sensor

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(POWER_PIN, GPIO.OUT)  # configure the power pin as an OUTPUT
    GPIO.setup(DO_PIN, GPIO.IN)

def loop():
    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # turn the rain sensor's power ON
    time.sleep(0.01)                   # wait 10 milliseconds

    rain_state = GPIO.input(DO_PIN)

    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.LOW)  # turn the rain sensor's power OFF

    if rain_state == GPIO.HIGH:
        print("The rain is NOT detected")
    else:
        print("The rain is detected")

    time.sleep(1)  # pause for 1 second to avoid reading sensors frequently and prolong the sensor lifetime

def cleanup():
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        setup()
        while True:
            loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cleanup()

        return False

# Function to log rain detection event with timestamp to CSV
def log_rain_event():
    # Get current timestamp
    timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Get rain detection status
    rain_detected = is_rain_detected()

    # Append rain event to CSV if rain is detected
    if rain_detected:
        with open('rain_log.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['Timestamp', 'Rain Detected']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            # Check if file is empty, if yes, write header
            if csvfile.tell() == 0:
                writer.writeheader()

            # Write the rain detection event
            writer.writerow({'Timestamp': timestamp, 'Rain Detected': 'Yes'})

# Example of how to continuously monitor the rain sensor and log events
while True:
    log_rain_event()
    time.sleep(1)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed to control the frequency of checks
```

---

```
import csv

import time

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO







# Function to check if rain is detected (replace this with your actual rain detection logic)

def is_rain_detected():

    POWER_PIN = 12  # GPIO pin that provides power to the rain sensor

    DO_PIN = 7     # GPIO pin connected to the DO pin of the rain sensor



def setup():

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(POWER_PIN, GPIO.OUT)  # configure the power pin as an OUTPUT

    GPIO.setup(DO_PIN, GPIO.IN)



def loop():

    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)  # turn the rain sensor's power ON

    time.sleep(0.01)                   # wait 10 milliseconds



    rain_state = GPIO.input(DO_PIN)



    GPIO.output(POWER_PIN, GPIO.LOW)  # turn the rain sensor's power OFF



    if rain_state == GPIO.HIGH:

        print("The rain is NOT detected")

    else:

        print("The rain is detected")



    time.sleep(1)  # pause for 1 second to avoid reading sensors frequently and prolong the sensor lifetime



def cleanup():

    GPIO.cleanup()





# Function to log rain detection event with timestamp to CSV

def log_rain_event():

    # Get current timestamp

    timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')



    # Get rain detection status

    rain_detected = is_rain_detected()



    # Append rain event to CSV if rain is detected

    if rain_detected:

        with open('rain_log.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:

            fieldnames = ['Timestamp', 'Rain Detected']

            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)



            # Check if file is empty, if yes, write header

            if csvfile.tell() == 0:

                writer.writeheader()



            # Write the rain detection event

            writer.writerow({'Timestamp': timestamp, 'Rain Detected': 'Yes'})



# Example of how to continuously monitor the rain sensor and log events

while True:

    log_rain_event()

    time.sleep(1)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed to control the frequency of checks
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? What didn't work? Please provide code, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: hello, i added another block of code i have tried which did not work as well as the error code. thanks for the response

Comment: `DO_PIN = 7` is outside of function?

Comment: I have indented that line. The error is regarding line 43.

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:

        setup()

        while True:

            loop()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        cleanup()



        return False.

return False being line 43. That is giving the error code:

return False ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: What specific problem do you have with the CSV writing?

Answer (score 0):

The line is regarding a syntax error, like you mentioned.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        setup()
        while True:
            loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cleanup()

        return False
```

You *cannot* use `return` outside of a `def`, because you are not returning something. You can remove that statement, since it has no added value to the code. You could also `raise` a `KeyboardInterrupt`, since that is what triggers the `except`.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I deleted the above statement from the code. Although it is not showing any errors, it is not displaying any data nor saving to a csv. I have updated my initial post with what the code now looks like... are you able to help? I'm not too sure about how to raise a keyboard interupt... i'm somewhat new